Is it possible to change the twilio conversations base url
Would any one have any idea how I could proxy the twilio conversation base url(s)?
ie. wss://tsock.us1.twilio.com to wss://chat.somedomain.com and then proxy the request on to twilio.
I am not seeing an obvious way to do this in the Android or iOS SDK's however it appears possbile in the javascript SDK.
Thanks
Alistair
